# Special characters in OData entity names / OData rest endpoints?

Tags: url, odata, special-characters

I have a scenario where my entity names can have special characters example : "Product-abc" which would make the url like this - ../odata/ProductService/Product-abc
However, OData (Apache Olingo) throws URI malformed error due to the presence of '-' , I suppose.
Anyone gone through similar situation and found a solution to display special characters in the endpoint url ?
To confirm, I tried debugging by removing the '-' and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to encode the special character?

You can try to replace '-' with '%2D'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).